# How to invent a new language in writing?

Tags: novel, language

I'm inventing a new planet with a new species and I don't have an official language for them. I need help with how to give them speech.

Comment: Biiggest point, to me, would be: Who will hear it? Will the characters all be members of this new species or will there be humans to meet them? If humans, I would stick to the "sound" of the language, describing what it sounds like. If no other species are involved, it also doesn't matter as much, some words would be enough (for specific concepts that don't translate easily). If a non-human other species is involved, then I also would stick with how the other language feels to them without going into details.

Comment: While I have not read it myself (yet), [this website](http://zompist.com/kit.html) is a big reference for learning to create languages. It also comes as a physical book.